# How could I get Ubuntu back in my boot menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I just reinstalled Windows 10 because of a problem I had and I can't access Ubuntu dual-boot anymore via the boot menu. There is still an entry named ubuntu and there is a new one called "OS on hard drive" that appeared when i tried to restore a Clonezilla image. However, **all of them lead to my fresh installation of Windows 10**. **The partitions containing the Ubuntu data are still here** and I didn't touch them.

Do you guys know what I could do to get Ubuntu back ?

Comment: I have fixed this sort of issue in the past using the `Boot Repair` tool. You need to boot to a Ubuntu live CD or USB then install and run the tool. Instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thank you so much it worked ! @codlord